# How to create unique key base on three field?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two foreign keys in table:

```
userId
visitorId
```

Also field `action`

I want to add constraints on these three field, that userId + visitorId + action will be unique.

How to do that in Workbench, MYSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a unique constraint:

```
alter table t add constraint unq_t_userid_visitorid_action
    unique (userid, visitorid, action);
```

You can also do this by creating a unique index:

```
create unique index unq_t_userid_visitorid_action on t(userid, visitorid, action);
```

You should be able to create an index through the Workbench GUI interface.

Comment: Thank you is it possible to do through Workbench?

Comment: When you create FK in Workbench, index will be created for you automatically. You need to go to the index and change it from INDEX to UNIQUE